# Device not recognize in android studio for android debugging

Tags: android, debugging, adb

My device Xiaomi Redmi MI A1 is running stock android, don't mistake it to be running MIUI.

Things I did :

(1) Enabled developer options and enabled USB debugging.

(2) Connected to my PC and downloaded Google's USB drivers for Android Studio as well as OEM USB drivers from Xiaomi.

(3) Installed it and also updated the device drivers from device manager by manually selecting the OEM USB driver file (it was showing no updates available afterwards), but Android Studio was still not recognizing my device.

(4) I also downloaded MI PC suite from their website but now it wasn't recognizing my device, I connected my device in PTP with USB debugging enabled.

I am using Windows 10 ( Version 1703; build 15063.632 )

My device config is AMD A6 processor at 1.8 GHz quadcore with 4GB RAM.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the `Turn on MiUI optimization` from developer options and restarting the device? I did the same and it worked on my MI device

Comment: Enable MIDI
Step 1: Goto settings > Additional Settings > Developer options
Step 2:In developer option, Enable developer options,
Step 3: In same menu go down in side Networking and from the SELECT USB CONFIGURATION, select MIDI

Now check adb devices on your command prompt you can see your Xiaomi is connected.

Comment: Can u please tell me how can I check for ADB devices in command prompt

Comment: `adb.exe devices` in the SDK platform-tools folder path to check for connected devices. From there you can restart the adb server, do it as admin by opening the command prompt with admin privileges and then `adb.exe kill-server` and `adb.exe start-server`. Be sure your USB cable allows data transfer (check with a different USB cable)

Answer (score 3):

try to do this things...

1) change your USB mode to file transfer .

2) enable to install from Unknown sources ....
    go to settings->additional settings/Privacy/Unknown Sources

3) also enable install via USB in developer options

4) restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the "Select USB Configuration" option to MTP.

It worked for me after installing the Mi PC Suite from here: pcsuite.mi.com

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the USB mode to PTP or any other, in some systems PTP is only recognised in Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

1. open file explorer
2. right click on my computer
   [image: my computer]
3. press on Manage

[image: manage]

3. open the device manager

[image: Device manager]

4. you can see unknown USB connected

[image: USB]

5. right click and press on update driver

[image: Update driver]

6. press on browse my computer

[image: Browse]

7. press on let me pick

[image: Let me]

8. press on USB composite and Next

[image: USB composite]

9. that it!! you will get a popup that your device is recognized now,
   you can see it in the device manager now, your USB is recognized now.

[image: Success]

Good luck!